# How does one find the index of an object in a list whose x and y position value match a given x and y

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, xna

I am creating a game that uses a tile system. Each tile is an object that has a Vector2 for its position. I have every tile in List.

I have another bit of code that generates a bunch of Vector2's  where trees should be placed on the grid of tiles. Every tree position is in a Vector2 in a List

My question is, how do I find the index of the tile that has an exact match of its coordinates in the List of tree coords. Once I find that I can then tell that tile object in the list to turn its treePresent boolean to true.

The tiles' gridPosition.X and gridPosition.Y:
0(1,9) 1(1,10) 2(2,1) 3(2,2)

The trees' treePosition.X and treePosition.Y :
0(1,9) 1(2,2)

I could then say: 
    tileList[0].treePresent=true;
    tileList[3].treePresent=true;

Answer (score 3):

A game using a tile system should NOT use a dynamic system (a list) for keeping track of the tiles.
I am assuming by "tile system" you refer to the entire game world/map divided into a 2D grid. The reason for this is two fold:

1. You potentially will use more memory to store a full map of data. If there is really not much going on in your world, and you will mostly (80% or much more) only see a blank/default background tile, then this rule may be proven invalid. However, for all cases with reasonable amount of data (which is what I am assuming here), you will use more memory as you have to store the tile type, and x&y coordinates, as opposed to just storing tile type.
2. Dynamic data structure is inefficient. Fetching tile data will take long in this manner, as you have to loop through your entire list to find a specific tile. So if you want tile (a,b), you have to loop through all your tiles (stopping once you have found the right tile), and comparing each (x,y) of every tile to (a,b). Doesn't sound very efficient, does it?

So the solution is simple:
Make a 2D array of tiles. The first dimension is for your x-coordinates, the second is for y.

For example:
worldData[x][y] (or equivalent to the language of your choice). In this manner, finding a tile is pretty instant. Here if I want tile (a,b), I simply call worldData[a][b]. No looping or comparisons needed.

Any questions?

Comment: How would I associate a tile object with a particular coordinate of an array so that when I have the 2d array I can call the tile? 

Do I create a 2darray of every tile position? If so, how does the tile know it is its?
I don't quite understand your last few lines about calling it mainly because I am fairly new to C# arrays myself; I had become quite accustomed to using lists.

Comment: I don't know C# syntax myself, maybe someone that does can help out. But the basic idea behind an array is that it is a set of a particular variable or object. So if you made a 1 dimensional array with say 10 integer elements, you can access them as intArray[0], intArray[1], intArray[2] and so on (where intArray is simply the name which I defined for the array). A 2D array is similar, except here we have 2 indices (intArray[0][0], intArray[1][0], intArray[0][1], etc).

Comment: So say you want a world that is 1000 by 1000 tiles. You will make a tile class firstly. Secondly you can make an array of tiles. Alternatively, if you have a unique ID for each tile, you can use that instead. SO say ID 0 is grass, ID 1 is water, ID 2 is trees, etc. Then you can make a 2D integer array as described above (the details on declaring the array you will have to look up yourself as I don't know C# syntax). Then you would be able to say tiles[0][0] = 1, will set the tile at position (x = 0, y = 0) to ID 1m which in this example is water.

Comment: if you make tiles[5][120] = 0, then (x = 5, y = 120) will represent grass. To draw the relevant tiles on screen, you would loop through the relevant portion of the 2D array. And say you want to check if your character (currently at x = 50, y = 60, for example) is in water, you can check tiles[char.xPos][char.yPos] == 1 (or C# equivalent). Do you get the idea yet?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
tileList.Where(t => treeList.Contains(t.Position));
```

If you are moving things around, beware that this compares for float equality, which can cause problems.

Answer (score 2):

You could also make a 2 dim list and reference the tile just by the tree position. Unless you're changing your grid size you shouldnt need to use a dynamic list and instead can create a 2 dimensional array